# JavaFX: Selecting a lot of rows in a large table

Tags: javafx, tableview

It seems a simple question, but I can't find a solution myself.

I have a TableView (to be frank I have two TableViews and would like to put the items from one to the other) with a large number of rows (for my tests, I had a little more than 6600) in it.

When I move the items, I would like to modify the selection of the destination table to be exactly the ones freshly selected.

```
@FXML
private TableView<PositionWrapper> source;

@FXML
private TableView<PositionWrapper> target;

private ObservableList<PositionWrapper> sourceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<PositionWrapper> targetList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


private void moveSourceToTarget(MouseEvent event) {
    // collecting selected items
    ObservableList<PositionWrapper> selectedItems = 
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

    // Adding selected items to the target
    targetList.addAll(selectedItems);

    // Removing selected items from source
    sourceList.removeAll(selectedItems);

    // Clearing the selection in both table (source has none of the 
    // selected items now, the target selection should be updated completely)
    target.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    source.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

    // My first try. Doesn't work (UnsupportedOperationException)
    target.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().setAll(selectedItems);

    // Second try: doing it one-by-one. Works, but extremely slow.
    selectedItems.stream().forEach(p -> target.getSelectionModel().select(p));
}
```

The second alternative works, but extremely slow. (How slow I don't know, because I killed my program after 20 seconds.)

My question: how to select a large number of rows in a TableView quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I made some deeper search and checked the implementation source code of the `MultipleSelectionModelBase` class. When selecting an item by row content (as I did in my second try), it iterates over all the items in the table to find the index of it, then calls the `select(int)` method with the index found.

It means that selecting several rows by content is an n*m algorithm, with a worst case of n^2 when selecting (almost) all items.

But this gave me the solution as well. As it is now proved to me that only the by-value selection suffers from the n^2 anomaly, the natural workaround is to use the index-based selection.

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void moveSourceToTarget(MouseEvent event) {
    [...]

    // Allocating an array to store indexes
    int[] idx = new int[selectedItems.size()];
    int p = 0;
    // Performance tuning to move selected items into a set 
    // (faster contains calls)
    Set<PositionWrapper> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        selectedItems.toArray(new PositionWrapper[0])));

    // Iterating over items in target list (but only once!)
    for (int i = 0; i < target.getItems().size(); i++) {
        if (s.contains(target.getItems().get(i))) {
            // and adding to the list of indexes when selected
            idx[p++] = i;
        }
    }
    // Calling the more effective index-based selection setter
    target.getSelectionModel().selectIndices(-1, idx);
}
```

Aftermath: the time required for selecting the 6600+ items reduced from 20+ sec to 0.1 sec.

BTW, I don't know why isn't `selectAll(S...)` is part of the JavaFX code...